# What can I reasonably expect a compiler to be able to inline?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Are there any general rules I can use for evaluating whether a modern compiler will inline a function? What is the relative cost of an extra stack frame (I know it's very small, but is there any way to generally quantify it - within an order of magnitude or so)?

I'm also particularly interested in:

- Can a compiler inline methods defined in a cpp?
- I know some compilers implement some optimizations even in debug (VS uses RVO in debug but not NRVO) - What's the situation for inlining? I would imagine that it's disabled so that we can see an expected call stack for debugging.

I'm currently trying to micro-optimize a memory tracking system, specifically ones that also apply without optimization enabled (in debug).

Comment: ...depends on the compiler....and any answer you get will be out dated in a very short time.

Comment: @dmckee I don't know much about compiler optimizations so I'll use RVO/NRVO as an example - you can be pretty sure those are implemented in every modern compiler and that won't become outdated anytime soon. I assume there are many similar optimizations. Also, I don't really see why any answer would be outdated in a very short time when a new C++ standard only appears once a decade.

Comment: Some compilers are smart enough to preserve debugability in spite of inlining and some other such optimizations, though they're probably in the minority.  I'm guessing the Visual Studio compilers can't.

Comment: Why ask how to predict things that you can easily measure? Use a debugger or disassembler to determine whether the compiler (or linker) inlined your function. Measure the execution time difference by writing a benchmark, trying it both ways, and comparing the results.

Comment: @bk1e You're right - there's no reason to have any information available which a person could figure out through experimentation themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to predict and hard to predict.  Simple expressions, like:

```
int a = b + (2 * c):
int d = e + (2 * c);
```

get optimized with the simplest optimizations (the `(2 * c)` "common subexpression" will only be computed once.

In C/C++, methods declared inlined generally will be (though not always).

Trickier are loop optimizations and the like.  Eg,

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    a = i + (2 * c);
}
```

the expression `(2 * c)` will usually get pulled out of the loop, in a compiler that does "global optimization", but not in one that does only "local optimization".  And, of course, expressions can get much more complicated and convoluted.

Change the body of the above loop to `a = i * (2 * c);`, and you progress to a slightly higher level of global optimization known as "loop induction".  A "smart" compiler will figure out to just add `2 * c` (as precomputed) to `a` for each iteration through the loop, vs doing the (more expensive) multiply on each iteration.

And that's just scratching the surface.

But I have no idea what the Visual Studio compilers are capable of.