# Copy constructor with default parameters never gets called

Tags: c++, llvm, clang, copy-constructor

Why is the output of the following program just `int3` and not `int3&4`?

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    explicit B(int i) { std::cout<<"int"<<i; }
    B(const B& rhs, int i = 0) { std::cout<<"&"<<i; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    B b(B(3), 4);
}
```

Command: `clang++ test.cpp -O0`

Compiler: Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)

Comment: It prints `int3&4` for me (GCC 4.6.2, `-O3`).

Comment: Actually my g++ 4.6.1 does print "int3&4".

Comment: +1 for short, complete test case. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug in clang](http://llvm.org/PR12139), which has [since been fixed](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20120305/054770.html). Copy-elision was incorrectly being applied to the constructor call, because clang wasn't checking how many arguments were provided before concluding that it was a copy construction.

The fix will be in the upcoming clang 3.1 release.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might have found a compiler quirk :)

If you change your compiler version to anything that's not LLVM 3.0, the output is int3&4.

This prints int3&4 on LLVm 3.0, so it seems to be related to the fact that B(3) is a temporary object:

```
class B
{
public:
    explicit B(int i)
    { 
        std::cout<<"int"<<i; 
    }
    B(const B& rhs, int i = 0) 
    { 
        std::cout<<"&"<<i; 
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    B a(3);
    B b(a, 4);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was a bug in clang, which has since been fixed. Copy-elision was incorrectly being applied to the constructor call, because clang wasn't checking how many arguments were provided before concluding that it was a copy construction.

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you post this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, RVO and NRVO ate your code. These special conditions allow the compiler to silently  eliminate object copies that would otherwise be enforced by the language. Since no copy was ever made as a result, then the code never prints the statement in the copy constructor.

Comment: Would RVO and NRVO be allowed even in Debug mode? As I understand it, they are optimizations and hence should be disabled when running in Debug mode, but in Debug mode I get "int3" too, on LLVM 3.0

Comment: Just thought I'd add this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556608/what-can-i-reasonably-expect-a-compiler-to-be-able-to-inline. Apparently, some compilers do selectively implement RVO and/or NRVO in debug mode too, which would explain LLVM's behaviour.

Comment: @carleeto: The compiler can legally do it whenever it likes.